# kdb how to pass a column name into a function

Tags: kdb

As a simplifying example, I have

```
tbl:flip `sym`v1`v2!(`a`b`c`d; 50 280 1200 1800; 40 190 1300 1900)
```

and I d like to pass a column name into a function like

```
f:{[t;c];:update v3:2 * c from t;}
```

In this form it doesnt work. any suggestion how I can make this happen?
Thanks

Comment: For your function definition you have some unnecessary semi-colons and you don't need to explicitly set the return with `":"`.
Adding a semi-colon to the end of your update statement suppresses the output which is why you would need to set the return of the function but by removing that semi-colon the function will return the output automatically.
So your function can look like `f:{[t;c] update v3:2 * c from t}`
You can also see another example of this in Thomas' answer.

Comment: ah, thanks, good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve this is using [`@` amend](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#amend):

```
q){[t;c;n] @[t;n;:;2*t c]}[tbl;`v1;`v3]
sym v1   v2   v3
------------------
a   50   40   100
b   280  190  560
c   1200 1300 2400
d   1800 1900 3600
```

This updates the column `c` in table `t` saving the new value as column `n`. You could also alter this to allow you to pass in custom functions too:

```
{[t;c;n;f] @[t;n;:;f t c]}[tbl;`v1;`v3;{2*x}]
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that fixed my problem

Comment: curious, how come you pass in : as third argument and the function as part of the 4th? The documentation shows the function would be the 3rd argument. Is the colon here some sort of identity function?

Comment: In this case `:` is the function as we are setting a value, the 4th argument `f t c` will be resolved to a list of values. On the [documentation](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#amend]) this would be an example of the usage `@[x;i;f;v]` where `v` is the list of vectors created by `f t c`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the functional form of the update statement.
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/#functional-sql

```
q)tbl:flip `sym`v1`v2!(`a`b`c`d; 50 280 1200 1800; 40 190 1300 1900)
q)parse"update v3:2*x from t"
!
`t
()
0b
(,`v3)!,(*;2;`x)
q){![x;();0b;enlist[`v3]!enlist(*;2;y)]} [tbl;`v2]
sym v1   v2   v3
------------------
a   50   40   80
b   280  190  380
c   1200 1300 2600
d   1800 1900 3800
```

Comment: thanks, looks like those functional forms are generally more flexible (and more confusing;))